# select second or third dropdown list on first dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

```
<select name="first" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
<select name="second" id="snack">
    <option value="1">snack 1</option>
    <option value="2">snack 2 second</option>
    <option value="3">snack 3 second</option>
</select>
<select name="third" id="drink">
    <option value="1">drink 1</option>
    <option value="2">drink 2</option>
    <option value="3">drink 3 third</option>
</select>
```

I want to change second or third dropdown menu on first dropdown 1st and 2nd option.
i.e. when we select Item 1 second dropdown should come up and when we select item 2 third dropdown should be up.

I have tried lot thing but couldn't achieve it. I'm looking for JavaScript solution

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: can you post some of the code you've tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Javascript solution:

**HTML**

```
<select name="first" id="select1" onchange="changeTime(this);">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
<select name="second" id="snack" style="display:none;">
    <option value="1">snack 1</option>
    <option value="2">snack 2 second</option>
    <option value="3">snack 3 second</option>
</select>
<select name="third" id="drink" style="display:none;">
    <option value="1">drink 1</option>
    <option value="2">drink 2</option>
    <option value="3">drink 3 third</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function changeTime (obj)
{
  if(obj.value == 1) {
     document.getElementById('snack').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById('drink').style.display='none';
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById('drink').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('snack').style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. this worked exactly as I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#drink').hide();

$('#select1').on('change', function () {
    if($('#select1').val() == 1) {
        $('#snack').show();
        $('#drink').hide();
    } else {
        $('#snack').hide();
        $('#drink').show();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ewwAX/604/

Comment: Yup Got the solution and this one is also correct.. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#snack").css({"display":"none"});            //using css function make snak & drink are hidden
        $("#drink").css({"display":"none"});            //use display property so that no effect on the layout .. no space taken by the hidden item
        $("#select1").change(function (){               // on change 
        var val = $("#select1").val();                  // of the value of select 1
        if(val == 1){                                   // if value = 1
        $("#snack").css({"display":"inline"});          // display snak
        $("#drink").css({"display":"none"});            // & hide drink
        }else if(val == 2){                             // if value = 2
        $("#snack").css({"display":"none"});            // hide snack
        $("#drink").css({"display":"inline"});          // display drink
        }else {                                         // other wise           
        $("#snack").css({"display":"none"});            // make all hidden
        $("#drink").css({"display":"none"});
        }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="first" id="select1">
        <option value="0" >Select Item</option>         <!-- this option added by me -- you can omit it if you want -->
        <option value="1" >Item 1</option>
        <option value="2" >Item 2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="second" id="snack">
        <option value="1">snack 1</option>
        <option value="2">snack 2 second</option>
        <option value="3">snack 3 second</option>
    </select>
    <select name="third" id="drink">
        <option value="1">drink 1</option>
        <option value="2">drink 2</option>
        <option value="3">drink 3 third</option>
    </select>

</body>
```

Comment: Try to add an explanation of why this works, to make it a more complete answer

Comment: Problem solved I used Beroza Paul's approach. Thank you so much for your help :)